# Is there any difference between // and m//?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl so this maybe a very stupid question but I couldn't find out :(

If I have:

```
$stringA =~ /regex/;
$stringB =~ m/regex/;
```

From my test, `$stringA` = `$stringB`. Is there any difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variable names as they're both treated 'specially' by Perl.

Comment: for reference, avoid using `$a` and `$b`, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 9):

This is a shorthand. You can omit the `m` when you use the delimiters `//`. Note that you can also use other characters to delimit, like `!`, but then you need to use m:

```
 if ($something =~ m!//this/has/a/ton/of//characters/in/it!)
```

It's often better to do that since it saves writing `\/\/` over and over, which you'd need to do if you used `//`.

Comment: When choosing your own delimiters, don't forget that `'` and `?` have special meanings when used with `m`.  See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m/PATTERN/msixpogc).

Answer (score 7):

`m/PATTERN/` and `/PATTERN/` are the same.

See [this part](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) of the perlop (perl operators) manpage. Scroll down to the section on `m/PATTERN/`, you'll see it's also known as `/PATTERN/`

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.

> The match operator. Coming before the opening delimiter, this is the "match" operator. It means read the string expression on the left of the =~, and see if any part of it matches the expression within the delimiters following the m. Note that if the delimiters are slashes (which is the normal state of affairs), the m is optional and often not included. Whether it's there or not, it's still a match operation.

[Source](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_m)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LaGrandMere Thanks for the info. I fixed my answer. Do you mind un-down voting? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just put a comment to have a better answer for the OP ... Since you've updated your answer, I'm going to upvote :)